# Count Exact Match using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, count, exact-match

I am trying to find the exact matching word using Excel VBA, but failed to do so as either due to case sensitivity or partial match.

Here is my data[image]

Experience Column contains certain keywords and I am extracting those keywords based on master list

The problems in **Result** are
It is showing UI2 means, UI 2 times, but as we can see in experience it is only 1 time

Same with GO, it shows 2 : One from Go and other from Google

NoSQL has been extracted into NoSQL and SQL, however there were two different skill set: NoSQL and SQL and since the experience doesn't have SQL, it shouldn't be extracted

There is a skill set called "R" in master file, it was difficult to extract particular R as it accounts for every R

Here is my code snip

[image]

I have read so many articles, but didn't find appropriate solution. Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post pictures of your code. Instead, post the code itself so people can copy/paste it if they want to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for word boundaries if you don't want "Go" to (eg) match "Google". You might be better off using a regex approach to find matches.

Note: to avoid matching "Go" with "go" you need the match to be case-sensitive, but to avoid misses on other terms you might need to pass all possible case variants like (eg) "mySQL|MySQL".

```vb
Sub matchTester()
    
    Dim s As String, skill
    
    s = "I go to school now and have used R, MySQL, noSQL and " & _
        "SQL and Go in my Ratings job at Google. I like R"
    
    For Each skill In Array("SQL", "noSQL|NoSQL", "mySQL|MySQL", "R", "Go", "VBA", "C#")
        Debug.Print skill, CountMatches(s, skill)
    Next skill

End Sub

Function CountMatches(sIn As String, countThis) As Long
    Dim regEx As Object, matches As Object
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\b(" & countThis & ")\b" 'add word boundaries
        Set matches = .Execute(sIn)
    End With
    CountMatches = matches.Count
End Function
```

output:

```txt
SQL            1 
noSQL|NoSQL    1 
mySQL|MySQL    1 
R              2 
Go             1 
VBA            0 
C#             0
```

Comment: If you want to match "Go" but not "go" then the regex needs to be case-sensitive.  If you don't want to make it case-sensitive then you need to (eg) filter out "go" from the results.  What's best really depends on your exact setup and how you maintain your list of search terms.

Comment: Thank you Tim for you response.  I am using Lcase or Ucase for case sensitivity

But this code throughs error if the skill is C++. It is saying Application/object defined error

Comment: Can you please explain what basically happning at Set matches = .Execute(sIn). Everything is clear. Much helps Thanks!

Comment: `Execute` is where you pass in the string to be analysed - you've already set up the regex object with a pattern to search for (and other settings such as ignore case), so this is the point where it tries to match the pattern and generate 0 or more "matches" which are returned to the `matches` collection.